# Porting Windows library using Qt to MacOSX, event loops

Tags: c++, objective-c, qt, events

I'm inserting a hook in the MFC message loop so that the Qt events are treated, without running ->exec() on qApp (because it's blocking):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK myHookFn(int ncode, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
    if (qApp) qApp->sendPostedEvents();
    return CallNextHookEx(0, ncode, wparam, lparam);
}
```

and

```
int argc = 0;
new QApplication(argc, NULL);
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, myHookFn, 0, threadId);
```

My question is:

What are the mechanisms equivalent to the MFC hook insertion that can be used under MacOSX so that sendPostedEvents could also be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should happen automatically with Qt Mac 4.5 (both Carbon and Cocoa ports) - since Qt's registered as a CFRunLoopSource in CFRunLoop and the callback will invoke sendPostedEvents. See also qeventdispatcher_mac.mm in src/gui/kernel of Qt 4.5